The Great Dictator Bonus Features -- Who's That Nazi?
There is a two-disk edition of Charles' Chaplin's film The Great Dictator in which the second disk contains, amongst the bonus features, an interview (apparently created for this disk) with someone identified as a member of Hitler's "inner circle." This person is interviewed (in German) about Hitler's attitude toward Chaplin, his belief that Chaplin was Jewish, his reaction to the film The Great Dictator, etc.
I'm curious to know more about this person. How did the film-makers find him and confirm that he was a member of Hitler's "inner circle"? Was this fact generally known about him? What was the inner circle, exactly? What was his relationship to Hitler? Etc.

I'm assuming you are referring to "The Tramp and the Dictator" (2002) which

...presented newly discovered footage of the film production (shot by Chaplin's elder half-brother Sydney) which showed Chaplin's initial attempts at the film's ending, filmed before the fall of France.
According to The Tramp and the Dictator, Chaplin arranged to send the film to Hitler, and an eyewitness confirmed he saw it.
Wikipedia re The Great Dictator

In other sources, there is a note that...

Reinhard Spitzy, a member of Hitler’s inner circle, is certain Hitler himself saw the film, more than once, and that he would have liked it, because he had a sense of humor. Albert Speer wrote to Oona Chaplin many years after the war to tell her, ” ‘The Great Dictator’ was the finest ‘documentary’ on the Third Reich.”
Variety.com

So who was Spitzy (who is credited at IMDB)?

Reinhard Spitzy, the son of Hans Spitzy, was born in Graz, Germany, on 11th February 1912. Spitzy was educated in Vienna. He then attended a military school. A supporter of Adolf Hitler he joined the Nazi Party in October, 1931 and the SS in January, 1932.
In 1936 he was appointed secretary to Joachim von Ribbentrop, the German Ambassador in London. In 1938 he returned to the Foreign Office in Berlin with Ribbentrop. He was a regular visitor to the Reich Chancellery where he met Eva Braun.
...
After the outbreak of the Second World War he was involved in negotiations with United States companies in Germany. By the summer of 1941, he was was working with Wilhelm Canaris, head of German military intelligence, the Abwehr. Spitzy worked from 1943 with Walter Schellenberg and Prince Max Egon zu Hohenlohe-Langenburg in the Reich Security Main Office.
Source

Spitzy seems to have been quite public about his relationship with Hitler 

...having written his memoirs, while was hiding in a Spanish monastery in 1946, and these were published in German in 1986.
Source


It seems amazing that they interviewed this unrepentant Nazi for a DVD bonus feature. I looked at his book at Amazon (whose German title translates "So we gambled away the realm."); customers who bought that book also bought a bunch of wacko conspiracy books. I was wondering (among other things) whether the impression Spitzy creates in the interview, of a personal friendship with Hitler, became general information only long after it could be easily corroborated.
